# how to convert sql query in ruby and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

```
SELECT A.FirstName, A.LastName, B.PatientId, B.RoomNumber, B.AdmissionDate, B.DischargeDate, B.MeasureCategory 
FROM DimPatient A, DimPatientStay B 
WHERE A.Id = B.PatientId AND A.FirstName = 'Anuj' AND B.MeasureCategory = 'ED'
```

hi some updation for this
i solved this prob by

```
MODELNAME.find_by_sql("your sql query")
```

Comment: What do you want with the query? What problem are you facing?

Comment: Could you please tell us more about your question, it's very hard to help if you don't state your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to find the result from sql query in Rails

```
query_params = Hash.new
    sql_query = "SELECT A.FirstName, A.LastName, B.PatientId, B.RoomNumber,    B.AdmissionDate, B.DischargeDate, B.MeasureCategory 
FROM DimPatient A, DimPatientStay B 
WHERE A.Id = B.PatientId AND A.FirstName = :first_name AND B.MeasureCategory = :measure_category"

query_params[:first_name] = first_name
query_params[:measure_category] = measure_category


@query_results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(
  ActiveRecord::Base.send("sanitize_sql_array",[sql_query, query_params] )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection().execute(#your_sql_here)
```

Comment: hey jamesMacLeod thanks for your reply but when i am executing my query it returns -1 how can i fetch my values??

**now my query is:-**
@users = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select A.FirstName,A.LastName,B.PatientId,B.RoomNumber,B.AdmissionDate,B.DischargeDate,B.MeasureCategory 
from [exim].[dbo].[DimPatient] A,[exim].[dbo].[DimPatientStay] B where A.Id = B.PatientId AND A.FirstName = 'Anuj'")

**logger.info("testing values #{@users}")**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A is one class and B is another, you should use **includes** as following:

```
A.includes(:b).where(...) # add you condition in where
```

I suggest to check good video tutorials of ActiveRecord [here](http://schneems.com/post/28125445535/active-record-deep-dive)